# How do I trap focus within a modal popup on iOS using the UIAccessibility protocol?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am launching a custom popup when the user clicks a button on iOS. How do I make sure that the focus stays within the custom popup (for accessibility reasons) when using voiceover on the iPhone? Currently the focus lands on the elements in the parent container as I swipe right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're targetting for iOS >= 5.0 then there is a property called [accessibilityViewIsModal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html). Using this definitely solve your problem.

If you're targetting for iOS < 5.0 then there is no a straight way for this. You need to customize your view controller's view and reorder the "_accessibleElements" as shown [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5). See the section **Make the Contents of Custom Container Views Accessible**.

Comment: accessibilityViewIsModal isnt working for me, is it still the true way to solve?